# Modelica - set min attribute

Tags: modelica

I want to create a new medium model in Modelica. All medium model have a type temperature with min, max, start and nominal attribute. I would like to set the minimum temperature to the value stored in `fluidLimits.TMIN` (which is an instance of a FluidLimits record) but I always get warnings stating that the min attribute is ignored, because it has a non-literal value. Writing `min=Modelica.Constants.small` instead works. 
See the first lines of my medium model definition below:

```
partial package SomeMediumModel
  extends Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialTwoPhaseMedium(
    Temperature(min=fluidLimits.TMIN, max=600));

  constant FluidLimits fluidLimits;
  ...
end SomeMediumModel;
```

Is there an example of how to use the FluidLimits record?
What do I have to change in order to make min accept the value from fluidLimits.TMIN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why this doesn't work.  It seems to me it should work since `fluidLimits` is a constant.  I'm guessing `FluidLimits` is a record?

It seems like a potential bug.  I'd report it to your tool vendor and see what they say.  In the meantime, a potential workaround would be to define a ***package*** like this:

```
partial package SomeMediumModel
  extends Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialTwoPhaseMedium(
    Temperature(min=FluidLimitsPackage.TMIN, max=600));

  package FluidLimitsPackage
    constant Modelica.Constants.Temperature TMIN=275;
  end FluidLimitsPackage;
  ...
end SomeMediumModel;
```

I suspect the issue you are having is that the tool just doesn't recognize that this is truly a constant.  This approach (which is untested, BTW) might work around that.  But in any case, you should definitely report it to your tool vendor to make sure they are aware of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your workaround, but did not yet get it to work in a satisfactory way. My tool is Dymola, I will contact dymola.support@3ds.com within the next days. FluidLimits is a record. Does it make a difference whether each variable inside FluidLimits is a constant or only fluidLimits is a constant instance of the FluidLimits record?

Comment: I think there are two problems: The variable TMIN in the FluidLimits record is of type Temperature and I want to use TMIN to set the min attribute of this type (which is defined in Modelica.Media), so there is some kind of loop. A solution to this would be to use Modelica.SIunits.Temperature in the definition of the FluidLimits record instead of the Modelica.Media definition. Second problem is the place where I set the min attribute: It does not work in the partial package (where fluidLimits.TMIN does not yet have value), but it does work in the final medium definition.